# Bootstrap 3.1.1 Navbar different layout when collapsed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to share the navbar across all devices, but I want it to format differently on small screens than on large.  I am new to Bootstrap so this might be obvious, but I am having trouble getting the menu right with a single set of code and not trying to do it with different rows and col-* settings.

[Bootply Sample](http://www.bootply.com/125375)
I want two things actually.  I would like the win and loss to be on the same line (which is close without the navbar-right) except they are not even in vertical position.
EDIT: I am able to correct this when removing navbar-right etc..., but do not get the navbar-right when the menu is condensed.

Secondly, I wanted the navbar-right, so when on a small display, all the badges align on the right hand side of the menu.

Is there a way to keep the menu smaller as well, so on a tablet it is not the whole width of the screen while on a phone it might be?

When the navbar normally draws, I want the badges beside the labels to keep the menu items smaller/closer together.  Only on the pull down menu do I want them to go to the right.

Do I need to create two copies of the navigation to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the badges seem aligned to me if you remove those `navbar-right` classes.  If you are using that class just to float them right, you should be using `pull-right` but in this case there's no need.

Second, if you wrap your badges inside another span, then you can use media queries to float the container right on mobile devices.

```
<span class="badges">
  <span class="badge alert-success">Win: 3</span>
  <span class="badge alert-danger">Loss: 1</span>
</span>

/* Note that you can use Bootstrap's '@screen-sm-min' variable if using LESS.*/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .badges {
    float: right;
  }  
}
```

If you want your navbar to be full width on mobile but not any other device, you could try something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/gujat/1/edit)**

---

**Edit**

For the changing width you can use Bootstrap's `col-*-*` classes like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That means for mobile it'll be full width, but anything from portrait tablet upwards will take up 10 of the 12 grid.

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/gujat/2/edit)

Comment: Is this something that can be done, without repetition, using the col-sm, col-xs, etc...?

Comment: The width issue can be - see my edit.  But the `.badges` part will be custom.